# Testing Right[Seq[MyClass]] and properties

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I am trying to implement a test with ScalaTest (`WordSpecLike`, `MustMatchers`) that verify if an `Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Value]]` contains one value and if the value has some specific attributes.

Ideally I would like to have something like:

```
val result:Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Value]] = ...
result.value must contain { _ have (
  'prop ("value")
)}
```

But this does not compile and I have no clue on how to achieve this kind of matching.

Is there documentation on deep tests or some best practices for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Inspectors`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.Inspectors) enable assertions to be made about collections, and in combination with [`EitherValues`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/other_goodies#eitherValues), as suggested by @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, and [checking arbitrary properties with `have`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingArbitraryProperties), the following syntax is possible

```
atLeast(1, result.right.value) must have ('prop ("value"))
```

Here is a working example

```
class Value(val foo: String, val bar: Int) {
  def isTooLong: Boolean = foo.length > 2
}

class StackOverflowSpec extends WordSpec with MustMatchers with EitherValues with Inspectors {
  "Result" when {
    "Right" should {
      "have property" in {
        val result: Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Value]] = Right(Seq(new Value("aa", 11), new Value("bbb", 42)))
        atLeast(1, result.right.value) must have ('tooLong (true), 'bar (42) )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively try pattern matching on result and passing the property predicate to [`Seq.exists`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html#exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) like so

```
class Value(val foo: String, val bar: String) {
  def isTooLong: Boolean = foo.length > 2
}

class StackOverflowSpec extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {
  "Result" when {
    "Right" should {
      "have property" in {
        val result: Either[Seq[Error], Seq[Value]] = Right(Seq(new Value("a", "b"), new Value("ccc", "ddd")))
        result match {
          case Left(seq) => fail
          case Right(seq) => seq.exists(_.isTooLong) must be(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I admit that it is not clear from my original question, but I was expecting a "more fluent" way of expressing that. Is that the "official" may of doing it with ScalaTest ?

Comment: I think ScalaTest have an special Mix-In for.working with **Eithers**, it does have it for **Trys**, which reduce a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez [`EitherValues`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.EitherValues)

Comment: Thanks, indeed `EitherValues`can simplify the code. But In my (specific) case I feel that pattern matching is more readable. Mainly because having a `Right(ofSomething)` is important and meaningful. Again, I was expecting a more fluent syntax but I start to be used with this simple "plain scala" syntax.

Comment: The drawback with this solution is that I have a vague message when the exists predicate did not match anything : _false was not true_

Comment: @gervais.b Please see edited answer. `Inspector` syntax which provides more informative messaging as well as enabling to use `must have` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. Sadly, in my case the value is know a a `Seq[SomeAbstractType]` and I should **(a)** ensure one item is a `ConcreteType` and **(b)** verify that this `ConcreteType` has a specific property with a given value. So I guess I need a specific matcher. But can still use the `Inspector` to validate that property.